# Finding shortest way between 3d points (x,y,z) in C#

Tags: c#, path-finding

Im having a lot of data stored as

```
public class Position{
 public double X{get;set;}
 public double Y{get;set;}
 public double Z{get;set;}
}
```

Now I would like to find the shortest path between two of these `Position` objects by going through the array of all `Position`

Like finding a path in a star map with known star positions, and I want to go from Star A to Star B, which path must I take...

My `Position` can have doubles with negative numbers

Constraint should be something like, max distance to next position (jumprange), and of course trying to find the path that generates minimum number of Positions i need to go through...

Comment: Sounds nice. Good luck.

Comment: Take a look a the [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) algorithm

Comment: You have said nothing about connectivity / navigability / cost. If you can go from any position to any other position, then the shortest way is the direct way.

Comment: You don't mention any constraints. In that case nothing stops you from going directly from A to B.

Comment: Ok the constraint should be something like,  max distance to next position, and of course trying to find the path that generates minimum number of Positions i need to go through... L

Answer (score -2):

There is a simple mathematical formula for this ,
Let's say u have :

```
var A = new Position();
var B = new Position();
//Assign value
```

Using the formula: √(A.X - B.X)^2 + (A.Y - B.Y)^2 + (A.Z - B.Z)^2) we have the following:

```
        public static double Distance(Position A, Position B)
        {
            var xDifferenceSquared = Math.Pow(A.X - B.X, 2);
            var yDifferenceSquared = Math.Pow(A.Y - B.Y, 2);
            var zDifferenceSquared = Math.Pow(A.Z - B.Z, 2);

            return Math.Sqrt(xDifferenceSquared + yDifferenceSquared + zDifferenceSquared);
        }
```

Comment: The OP wanted a path which runs through certain points, didn't he?